# Mosby Framework - getView cause ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, mosby

I just create a simple/blank fragment, which should use the `Mosby`Framework. Every time I'm using the `getView()`method I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   de.xxx.projectZ.packA.AFragment cannot be cast to
>   de.xxx.projectZ.packA.AView

```
public interface AView extends MvpLceView<List<Persons>> {
  // empty
}
```

My presenter which cause the error

```
public class APresenter extends MvpBasePresenter<AView> {
    PersonsRepository personsRepository;

    @Inject
    public APresenter(PersonsRepositoryImpl personsRepository) {
        this.personsRepository = personsRepository;
    }

    public void loadPersons() {
// ERROR
        if (isViewAttached())
            getView().showLoading(true);

        List<Person> persons = personsRepository.getPersons();


        if (isViewAttached()) {

        }
    }
}
```

My fragment header

```
public class PersonsFragment
        extends MvpLceFragment<SwipeRefreshLayout, List<Person>, AView, APresenter> {
```

Does anybody know why this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Fragment is not implementing `AView` ...

```
public class PersonsFragment
        extends MvpLceFragment<SwipeRefreshLayout, List<Person>, AView, APresenter> 

        implements AView  // This is missing
{
 ...
}
```